# AnyConnect SSL VPN Connected but unable to ping my inside LAN

Tags: vpn, ssl, cisco-anyconnect

I am trying to configure Anyconnect SSL VPN and it is killing me, I am able to connect to the VPN on a laptop, witch is able to download the anyconnect client from the ASA and I can also connect to the VPN using the Cisco anyconnect app but...

I am unable to ping any of my IP's that are on the inside of my ASA. Before posting here I have spent many hours on forums and watching videos on anyconnect SSL VPN creation and I am following it to the T but still no ping. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Inside      10.17.1.254/24
Outside     192.168.1.254/24
VPN Pool    10.99.1.1-50/24

Inside LAN  10.17.1.0/24
```

---

```
    ASA Version 8.4(2)
    !
    hostname ciscoasa
    enable password ft5r/Vn.VedHFe0u encrypted
    passwd 2KFQnbNIdI.2KYOU encrypted
    names
    !
    interface Ethernet0/0
     switchport access vlan 2
    !
    interface Ethernet0/1
    !
    interface Ethernet0/2
    !
    interface Ethernet0/3
    !
    interface Ethernet0/4
    !
    interface Ethernet0/5
    !
    interface Ethernet0/6
    !
    interface Ethernet0/7
    !
    interface Vlan1
     nameif inside
     security-level 100
     ip address 10.17.1.254 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface Vlan2
     nameif outside
     security-level 0
     ip address 192.168.1.253 255.255.255.0
    !
    ftp mode passive
    object network obj_any
     subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
    object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.99.1.0_26
     subnet 10.99.1.0 255.255.255.192
    pager lines 24
    logging asdm informational
    mtu inside 1500
    mtu outside 1500
    ip local pool ACPool 10.99.1.1-10.99.1.50 mask 255.255.255.0
    icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
    no asdm history enable
    arp timeout 14400
    nat (inside,outside) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.99.1.0_26 NETWORK_OBJ_10.99.1.0_26 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
    !
    object network obj_any
     nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
    timeout xlate 3:00:00
    timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
    timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
    timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
    timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
    timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
    timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
    dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
    user-identity default-domain LOCAL
    http server enable
    http 10.17.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
    no snmp-server location
    no snmp-server contact
    snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
    telnet timeout 5
    ssh timeout 5
    console timeout 0

    dhcp-client client-id interface outside
    dhcpd auto_config outside
    !
    threat-detection basic-threat
    threat-detection statistics access-list
    no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
    webvpn
     enable outside
     anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-2.5.2014-k9.pkg 1
     anyconnect enable
     tunnel-group-list enable
    group-policy GroupPolicy_ACSSLVPN internal
    group-policy GroupPolicy_ACSSLVPN attributes
     wins-server none
     dns-server value 10.17.1.1
     vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-client
     default-domain none
    username Earth password YwTxEzMBQFaeRlOE encrypted
    tunnel-group ACSSLVPN type remote-access
    tunnel-group ACSSLVPN general-attributes
     address-pool ACPool
     default-group-policy GroupPolicy_ACSSLVPN
    tunnel-group ACSSLVPN webvpn-attributes
     group-alias ACSSLVPN enable
    !
    class-map inspection_default
     match default-inspection-traffic
    !
    !
    policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
     parameters
      message-length maximum client auto
      message-length maximum 512
    policy-map global_policy
     class inspection_default
      inspect dns preset_dns_map
      inspect ftp
      inspect h323 h225
      inspect h323 ras
      inspect rsh
      inspect rtsp
      inspect esmtp
      inspect sqlnet
      inspect skinny
      inspect sunrpc
      inspect xdmcp
      inspect sip
      inspect netbios
      inspect tftp
      inspect ip-options
    !
    service-policy global_policy global
    prompt hostname context
    call-home reporting anonymous prompt 2
    Cryptochecksum:48f9a08dc4ac36ac9bf227fb0df7080f
    : end
    ciscoasa#
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You've done just fine on your first post, the guidelines can be found in [our FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) and you can always ask any questions regarding the site or a specific action by someone on [our meta](http://meta.superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

You have to define split tunnel access-list. First create an access-list:

```
access-list SPLIT_TUNNEL permit ip 10.17.1.0 255.255.255.0 any
```

Then go the the group policy:

```
group-policy GroupPolicy_ACSSLVPN attributes
  acl SPLIT_TUNNEL
```